# Install pydantic using poetry and pip throws ERROR

Tags: python, macos, pip, pydantic, python-poetry

I install pydantic with poetry. It works fine But when try to use Pydantic after installing it throws

```
E   ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sazzad/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-test-project-qHFD2Grb-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/sazzad/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-test-project-qHFD2Grb-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/sazzad/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-test-project-qHFD2Grb-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/sazzad/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-test-project-qHFD2Grb-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

Then I tried this
 `pip uninstall pydantic && python3.9 -m pip install --no-binary :all: pydantic --nocache-dir` from pottery venv

I get this error

```
            creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/import_hook.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/maturin
            running egg_info
            creating maturin.egg-info
            writing maturin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
            writing dependency_links to maturin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
            writing requirements to maturin.egg-info/requires.txt
            writing top-level names to maturin.egg-info/top_level.txt
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
            warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'src/python_interpreter'
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            running build_ext
            running build_rust
            error: can't find Rust compiler
      
            If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.
      
            To update pip, run:
      
                pip install --upgrade pip
      
            and then retry package installation.
      
            If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Note: I am using macos which arm64 not x86 as you already noticed in the log.

Any clue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an older version of Pydantic to solve the issue. If someone has a better solution, I am happy to follow.

```
pip install --no-binary :all: pydantic==1.10.8
```

Comment: I fixed this with upgrading pip and setuptools to latest version